# how to return values in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, calling-convention

I'm fairly new to python and I am trying to work with a dictionary filled with keys that resemble the following layout:

```py
    dict = {
        'Tim': ['red', 'pizza', 'soda'],
        'Jake': ['green', 'burger', 'juice'],
        'Mary': ['blue', 'salad', 'water']
    }
```

How would I go about letting a user input a name and then set the contents of that person's information as values of variables in the code?
For example, if a user chooses to view information about Jake, then:

```
    favoriteColor = green
    favoriteFood = burger
    favoriteDrink = juice
```

I really just don't know how to call specific values in this specific type dictionary in python. Would it be something similar to this:

```py
favoriteColor = dict.Jake[0]
favoriteFood = dict.Jake[1]
favoriteDrink = dict.Jake[2]
```

Comment: Using lists like this is not a good pattern. See my answer for a different approach

Comment: It's no biggie, but I'd avoid naming your dictionary as `dict` - it wont break anything, but normally, dict is a reserved(ish) keyword that describes the dictionary data-type. In our house style guide, we often place an underscore_d at the end of the variable name if we want to signify something is a dict, like `person_preferences_d`, that way, the variables describe what they're about, but retain a signifier as to their "dict-ness".

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, it's not the best idea to name a variable `dict`, as it already means something in python, so I'll redefine it as **`favsDict`** for context in the rest of my answer.

```py
favsDict = { 'Tim': ['red', 'pizza', 'soda'],
             'Jake': ['green', 'burger', 'juice'],
             'Mary': ['blue', 'salad', 'water']    }
```

---

> *I really just don't know how to call specific values in this specific type dictionary in python*

You might like to take a look at the documentation on [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and how to access values with keys [as well as [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), the values of which can be accessed with indices], but below are some examples with `favsDict`:

- <kbd>`favsDict['Jake']`</kbd> should return `['red', 'pizza', 'soda']`
- <kbd>`favsDict['Tim'][0]`</kbd> should return `'red'`
- <kbd>`favsDict['Mary'][2]`</kbd> should return `'water'`
- <kbd>`tim_ffood = favsDict['Tim'][1]`</kbd> should effectively be the same as `tim_ffood = 'pizza'`

---

> *How would I go about letting a user input a name and then set the contents of that person's information as values of variables in the code?*

It's common to use the built-in [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function to prompt and get user input, and there are many ways to set the variables. ([View tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77qbS.gif) of the example below.)

```py
search_name = input('Please enter a name: ')
if search_name in favsDict:
    favsList = favsDict[search_name]

    # favoriteColor, favoriteFood, favoriteDrink = favsDict[search_name] # = favsList ## OR
    # favoriteColor,favoriteFood,favoriteDrink = favsList[0],favsList[1],favsList[2] ## OR

    favoriteColor = favsList[0] # favsDict[search_name][0]
    favoriteFood = favsList[1] # favsDict[search_name][1]
    favoriteDrink = favsList[2] # favsDict[search_name][2]

    for fCat, fVal in zip(['color','food','drink'], favsList): 
        print(f"\t{search_name}'s favourite {fCat} is {fVal}")
else: print(f'! Could not find any records for {repr(search_name)} !')
```

---

If you want to build `favsDict` from user input <sup>([view test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVsyE.png))</sup> and you have a set number of people to add:

```py
personsCt = 3 # how many names/people
fav_categories = ['Color', 'Food', 'Drink'] # list template for asking

favsDict = {input(f'\n[Person#{i+1}] Please Enter\n\tName: '): [
    input(f'\tFavorite {f}: ') for f in fav_categories
] for i in range(personsCt)}

print()
favsDict
```

If you want to let the user decide when to stop, you can use a `while` loop <sup>([view test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrdt8.png))</sup>

```py
fav_categories = ['color', 'food', 'drink'] # list template for asking
favsDict = {} # initiate

while (pName := input(f'\n[Just press Enter to exit]\nEnter name: ')):
    fPromptr = lambda fc: input(f"\t{pName}'s favorite {fc} is: ")
    favsDict[pName] = [fPromptr(fCat) for fCat in fav_categories]

print()
favsDict
```

<sup>Btw, the [walrus operator](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-assignment-expressions-in-python) `:=` only works in python 3.8 or higher; without it, you'd need *`pName=input(...)`* before and at the end of *`while pName:...`* [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWd57.png).</sup>

**Note that if any names are repeated, only the most recently entered data for that name will remain.**

Answer (score 0):

you can access each entry in the dictionary like this:

```
dict["Jake"]
```

which would return the list

```
['green', 'burger', 'juice']
```

Then you can just grab whichever element you need from that list like so (for example their favorite color):

```
dict["Jake"][0]
```

which would return

```
'green'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do achieve this by first using the .get() method, then filtering them out by their specific variables.

For example, you could use the following snippet as an overview of how to do this:

```
# Initial dictionary
dict = {
    'Tim': ['red', 'pizza', 'soda'],
    'Jake': ['green', 'burger', 'juice'],
    'Mary': ['blue', 'salad', 'water']
}

# Check input for name
name = input("Enter a name:")

# Returns values for inputted name in dictionary
name_values_in_dict = dict.get(name)

# If it is none, return that it could not be found.
if name_values_in_dict is None:
     print("Name could not be found in dictionary.")

# If it is found, store in variables and print them out.
favoriteColor = name_values_in_dict[0]
favoriteFood = name_values_in_dict[1]
favoriteDrink = name_values_in_dict[2]

print(f'Favorite color is: {favoriteColor}, favorite food is: {favoriteFood}, and favorite drink is: {favoriteDrink}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list where each element implicitly corresponds to some type (in this case colour, food, drink) is rarely a good idea. Much better to use a class. Then, with judicious variable naming, it's quite obvious what each value means. Something like this:

```
class Favourites:
    def __init__(self, food, colour, drink):
        self._food = food
        self._colour = colour
        self._drink = drink
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self._food=} {self._colour=} {self._drink=}'

database = dict()

while (name := input('Name: ')):
    food = input('Food: ')
    colour = input('Colour: ')
    drink = input('Drink: ')
    database[name] = Favourites(food, colour, drink)

print(database)
```

Now we can enter "favourites" for multiple people. Just hit return (empty input) to break the loop and see what's been constructed

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're new I will try to explain a little bit.

> First off, try to not use reserved words as variable names `dict` is a python reserved word for the type `dictionary`.

Also for user input I recomend you to read: [Basic Input, Output, and String Formatting in Python](https://realpython.com/python-input-output/)

#### A very high view of Dicts ...

A Python dictionary is a collection of Key-Value pairs, meaning that you have several items each with an "index" or "name" (the key) and a value (anything, in your case, lists)

So when you have:

```
MyDict = {
    'Tim': ['red', 'pizza', 'soda'],
    'Jake': ['green', 'burger', 'juice'],
    'Mary': ['blue', 'salad', 'water']
}
```

That means you have 3 keys, Tim, Jake, and Mary, so if you use the key `Tim` you will be accessing the value of that item which is the list: `['red', 'pizza', 'soda']` and for getting the first element of that list you could:

```
tim_favorite_color = MyDict['Tim'][0]

# Which is the same as:
tim_favorites = MyDict['Tim']
tim_favorite_color = tim_favourites[0] # red
```

#### Addendum

In order to make your code more readable you could use another data structure for the list of favorites, I would suggest a [namedtuple](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/namedtuple-in-python/).

```
from collections import namedtuple

FavoriteValues = namedtuple("FavoriteValues", ["color", "food", "drink"])
Favorites = {
    'Tim': FavoritesValues('red', 'pizza', 'soda')
}
# This allows you write code like:
Favorites['Tim'].food  # pizza
```

#### Even better...

> I will tet somethig for you, you will have to search info about
> classes and lambda  ;)

So, the other thing you would like to use to make your code even better, is use [DefaultDict](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/defaultdict-in-python/) and class.

```
from collections import defaultdict


class TFavorite:

    def __init__(self, color, food, drink):
        self.color = color
        self.food = food
        self.drink = drink

Favorites = defaultdict(lambda: TFavorite('unknown', 'unknown', 'unknown'))

# prints 'unknown' first time we lookup for Tim
# so no previous info.
print(Favorites['Tim'].color) 

Favorites['Tim'].color = 'red'
print(Favorites['Tim'].color) # prints 'red'

print(Favorites['Tim'].food) # still unknown
```